# Typescript push to specific key in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I am working on Angular2 project using Firebase.

I need to push all query results under the same key in `this.guestPush`.

I have a multiple select element which contains different user levels. 4, 6, 9.

When one level is selected, the resulting object is saved in the `guestPush` array, but when another level is selected the following error occurs.

I get this error:

> ERROR TypeError: *this.guestPush[("filter*" + i)].push is not a function

Here is my code :

```
  guestPush: any[] = new Array;

  level.forEach((lvl, index) => {

    this.db.object(`levelsUsers/${lvl}/users`)
      .subscribe(users => {

        if (this.guestPush['filter_' + i]) {
          this.guestPush['filter_' + i].push(users);
        } else {
          this.guestPush['filter_' + i] = users;
        }

      }, err => console.log(err));

  });
```

Edit ***

The users object which contains the user or users which match the filter:

```
Object {-KmSjAaxdCUvrPEQ8InI: Object, $key: "users", $exists: function}
  -KmSjAaxdCUvrPEQ8InI: Object
    admin:"false"
    description:"desc"
    ...
    ...
    verified:false
  __proto__:Object
  exists:function ()
  $key:"users"
  __proto__:Object
```

And `this.guestPush[i] = users;` creates an object like this:

```
[Object]
 0:Object
 -KmSjAaxdCUvrPEQ8InI: Object
    admin:"false"
    description:desc"
    ...
    ...
    verified:false
    __proto__:Object
  $exists:function ()
  $key:"users"
  __proto__:Object
 length:1
 __proto__:Array(0)
```

So in the next loop I want to add any new user objects next to `-KmSjAaxdCUvrPEQ8InI` or anything as long as it is added as a value of the `0` key.

Comment: You have the line "this.db.object", maybe changing that to a list subscription will help?  If you're using angularfire, that's returning an object, so thus no push method.  [Reference](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/4-querying-lists.md)

Comment: Since everything here's an arrow function, i'm kind of lost with `this`, is `guestPush` a variable or a property?

Comment: It's a property.

Comment: Typescipt supports future features from JS. One of those is Map. You can rewrite your code not treating your array as a map. It will be more readable and transparent for you

Comment: Where is 'i' coming from? Do you mean 'index'?

Comment: The i is coming from the template. I use some nested form elements. So the `i` just represents each of those elements.

Comment: `this.guestPush['filter_' + i]` what is this? Are you assigning static members to an Array? your `guestPush` variable should be of type `any`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I ended up using

```
 this.guestPush.push({ [i]: { [key]: obj } });
```

Answer (score 11):

Looks like you are getting an array response and you are assigning it to the object :

```
this.guestPush['filter_' + i] = users;
```

so `this.guestPush['filter_'+ i]` is of type array now. If you want to add another `users` object to it , you are essentially adding another array to existing array. In that case shouldn't you be using `concat` ?

```
if (this.guestPush['filter_' + i]) {
    this.guestPush['filter_' + i].concat(users);
} else {
    this.guestPush['filter_' + i] = users;
}
```

if `users` is not an array, then it should be

```
if (this.guestPush['filter_' + i]) {
    this.guestPush['filter_' + i].push(users);
} else {
    this.guestPush['filter_' + i] = [users];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

@Ciprian : As per your answer.

You need a small change from your code to use. I hope this below code enough to you.

```
let key ='filter_';
this.guestPush.push({ key + i : users });
```

Comment: I need to add the key as object key when saving to database. each represent a user. and I also need to delete objects based on `i`

Answer (score 2):

Here's your problem,

```
guestPush: any[] = new Array;
'filter_' + i // this will yield a string.
this.guestPush['filter_' + i])
```

I could define an object:

```
let name = {};
name['x'] = 'blah';
or name.x = 'blahblah'; // name.x does same thing as name['x']
```

I think your thinking `name['x'] = 'blah';` is an array, when it's object syntax.

Consequently you need to think about implementing a [Dictionary](http://www.dustinhorne.com/post/2016/06/09/implementing-a-dictionary-in-typescript).

Answer (score 1):

> Typescript push to specific key in array

You need to use the `splice` method *on the array* : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Comment: He's trying to access keys that aren't indexed though

Comment: I tried splice ... `this.guestPush['filter_' + i].splice(1, 0, users);` but it's giving me the same error. `VM3282:27 ERROR TypeError: _this.guestPush[("filter_" + i)].splice is not a function
    at SafeSubscriber._next`

Comment: @CiprianCirstea your `this.guestPush` is an array, why are you trying to use index of `string type`, did that really exist? also `users` is an `object`, you are trying to use it as array.

Comment: So what index type should I use. I tried using a number  type but I was having difficulties with it. I ll try again.